# How to clear user data in android programmatically?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

Hello i am new in android , i followed a [tutorial](http://www.javaexperience.com/how-to-clear-user-data-in-android/) which explain how to clear app data in android, but when ever i am trying to clear my data i am getting an error of null object reference.

Main.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
        Button b;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.start);  
            addDataInAppDir();

            b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    ClearDataApplication.getInstance().clearApplicationData(getBaseContext());  
                }


            });
        }

        private void addDataInAppDir() {
            SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("sample", 0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("key1", true);
            editor.putString("key2", "Some strings in prefs");
            editor.commit();

            try {

                final String FILECONTENT = "This is string in file samplefile.txt";
                FileOutputStream fout = openFileOutput("samplefile.txt", MODE_PRIVATE);
                OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fout);
                osw.write(FILECONTENT);
                osw.flush();
                osw.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


    }
```

ClearDataApplication.java

```
  public class ClearDataApplication extends Application 
    {
        private static ClearDataApplication instance;

           @Override
           public void onCreate() {
               super.onCreate();
               instance = this;
           }

           public static ClearDataApplication getInstance() {
               return instance;
           }

           public void clearApplicationData(Context mContext) {

               File cache = mContext.getCacheDir();  
               File appDir = new File(cache.getParent());

               if(appDir.exists()) {
                   String[] children = appDir.list();

                   for(String s : children) {
                       if(!s.equals("lib")) {
                           deleteDir(new File(appDir, s));
                       }
                   }
               }
           }


           public static boolean deleteDir(File dir) {
               if (dir != null && dir.isDirectory()) {
                   String[] children = dir.list();
                   for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
                       boolean success = deleteDir(new File(dir, children[i]));
                       if (!success) {
                           return false;
                       }
                   }
               }

               return dir.delete();
           }
    }
```

Logcat

```
10-10 16:25:55.589: E/AndroidRuntime(6121): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-10 16:25:55.589: E/AndroidRuntime(6121): Process: com.example.fetchdata, PID: 6121
10-10 16:25:55.589: E/AndroidRuntime(6121): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.example.fetchdata.ClearDataApplication.clearApplicationData(android.content.Context)' on a null object reference
10-10 16:25:55.589: E/AndroidRuntime(6121):     at com.example.fetchdata.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:29)
10-10 16:25:55.589: E/AndroidRuntime(6121):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
10-10 16:25:55.589: E/AndroidRuntime(6121):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
10-10 16:25:55.589: E/AndroidRuntime(6121):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
10-10 16:25:55.589: E/AndroidRuntime(6121):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
10-10 16:25:55.589: E/AndroidRuntime(6121):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
10-10 16:25:55.589: E/AndroidRuntime(6121):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
10-10 16:25:55.589: E/AndroidRuntime(6121):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
10-10 16:25:55.589: E/AndroidRuntime(6121):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
10-10 16:25:55.589: E/AndroidRuntime(6121):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
10-10 16:25:55.589: E/AndroidRuntime(6121):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Comment: instead of getting base context, use "this" keyword

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The NPE is saying that your `ClearDataApplication.getInstance()` is returning null.

ClearDataApplication extends Application so that means it's intended to be your representation of the Application for the lifetime of the running process. You don't need that getInstance() method as the runtime already guarantees you that there will only be one instance. Instead, from your activity, call `getApplication()` and cast it to ClearDataApplicatiom.

In order for the above to work, you also need to make a change in your manifest file to specify that ClearDataApplication is what should be used as the representation of the Application.

```
<application android:name=".ClearDataApplication" ...>
```

Reference:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#nm

Answer (score 0):

Did you add `android:name="**/ClearDataApplication"` under application tag in manifest.xml?Like

```
<Application
    android:name="path of ClearDataApplication"
    ...
</Application>
```

Comment: Yes i have declared it in Manifest.xml

Comment: Suggest you add a debug log in ClearDataApplication#onCreate,to see if the method has been called.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the ClearDataApplication the app's application in your android manifests file. It's possible the onCreate method in the ClearDataApplication class is not called.